# Capturing Standard Error

Tags: c#, standard-error

I'm following the guidance of other SO articles on this topic, but I have been unable to find what I need. I have the following codeblock which launches - in this case - a known corrupted .msi (in order to test the retrieval of the standard error message):

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + thirdPartyApp.Item2.InstallString);
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
writeEvent(EventLogEntryType.Information, "Attempting to launch upgrade: " + thirdPartyApp.Item2.InstallString, "Third Party Update");
proc.Start();
string stderror = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

When manually launched, this .msi throws error code 1620 with message "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

While debugging, if I look at proc.ExitCode its value is 1620 - so it's capturing that correctly. I added the line `string stderror = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();` to attempt to capture the error text, but after the process executes and errors out stderror has a value of "".

How can I grab the actual error text into a variable?

Comment: Are you sure proc even writes to StdErr? I mean, it is a windowed app, writing to the console could never have been implemented. Instead they just parse the errorcode to display a MessageBox.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you use a Try/Catch block to catch the error?  I believe the text you are looking for would be in the ex.message.  I have to confess I don't know what the result would be with proc.start though, it's worth a try?

Comment: Tried the Try/Catch block, but the errant install file actually doesn't cause an exception. So I can't capture the exception message.

Comment: Try using `msiexec.exe` instead of `cmd.exe`.